# React-router 2.4.1 activeClassName for links with hash

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app navbar a have routing like this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: 'key' }} activeClassName='active' />
<Link to={{ pathname: 'key', hash: 'value1' }} activeClassName='active' />
<Link to={{ pathname: 'key', hash: 'value2'}} activeClassName='active' />
...
```

so routes are like this: `/key`, `/key#value1`, `/key#value2`..., but when I choose any route from this list - all routes becomes active.
Is there way to do active only chosen route with hashes?